# Troubleshooting refresh rate

Tags: resolution, monitor

I have been having problems with my refresh rate and it's recommended and default rate is 60ghz. It keeps flickering at every rate I put it. Does anyone have ideas how to resolve this? thank you

Comment: are you in the United States?

Comment: yeah, I am in the US

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the correct graphics driver, that is, more importantly, make sure your hardware is accurately detected. The easiest way to do this is to go to "Settings" and under "System" click on the "Details" icon.

You should see your CPU and GPU chipsets referenced here listed over on the right hand side of the window.

If you see something like "Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe" listed here and you are **not** using this chipset . . . you have found the problem and you need to install the proper drivers for your hardware.

Ubuntu and other like distros usually end up with the Gallium driver as a fallback when either the hardware is not properly detected or the proper drivers are not available, loaded, or installed. This usually causes all kinds of visual shuddering and display issues.